# How to solve the pair of equations $4a-11b+12c=22$ and $a+5b-4c=17$ over the integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics

Solve the systems if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers:

> $$4a-11b+12c=22$$
>
> $$a+5b-4c=17$$

The answer is given in the back as $(7,6,5)$ but how can you approach three variables with only two equations?

I tried multiplying the second equation by 3 and adding I got this

$$7a + 4b=73$$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The solution for this system of equations will look something like this: $a=A_1+A_2*p$, $b=B_1+B_2*p$ and $c=p$. And from this, you should search integer solutions.

Comment: Note the requirement that $a,b,c$ are integers. Try multipling the second equation by $3$ and adding ... edit your findings into the question, so we can see some attempt from you.

Comment: $7a\color{red}{+}4b=73$.& this has solutions in positive integers $(a,b)=(3,13)$ or $(7,6)$ ... so ...

Comment: Now consider this equation modulo $4$ to find a value for $a$ and then construct the possible positive solutions.

Comment: Modulo refers to taking the remainder on division, so taking an equation modulo $4$ results in one of $0,1,2,$ or $3$.  For integer equations you can often eliminate cases that way.  I think $\bmod 7$ is more useful here.

Comment: @user685252 You know that $a \le 10$, and you can see that $a$  must be an odd number. Then there are $5$ potential values remaining for $a$, which you can try one by one.

Comment: " but how can you approach three variables with only two equations"  The fact that these must be positive integers is an additional restraint that limits the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given $7a+4b=73$ you can take it $\bmod 7$ to get $4b \equiv 3 \bmod 7, b \equiv 6 \bmod 7$.  This gives $b=6$ or $13$ because $20$ is too large.  Plugging in, you find $13$ is too large as well.

If you want to do it without the modulo operation, note that $a \lt 11$ because otherwise $7a \gt 73$, so you only have ten choices and can try them all.

Comment: Also note that $a$ must be odd, so that cuts the choices down to $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Once you find one solution in integers, any other solution happens by adding an integer multiple of the coefficient cross product, namely 
$$ \langle -16, 28, 31 \rangle  $$
You know the solution $ \langle 7,6,5 \rangle \; .  $
Any other integer solution is 
$$ \langle 7-16t, 6+28t, 5+31t \rangle \; .  $$
If $t > 0$ we get $7 - 16 t < 0.$ If $t < 0$ then $6 + 28 t < 0.$ It follows that $t=0,$ the only solution in positive integers is the given one. There are infinitely many integer solutions, they lie on the line I described, but that line passes only briefly through the first (positive) octant.

Comment: @user685252 you have a difficult life. I wish you the strength to carry on.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the equations as
\begin{align*}
-11b+12c&=22-4a\\
5b-4c&=17-a
\end{align*}
which gives us
\begin{align*}
b&=\frac{73-7a}4\\
c&=\frac{297-31a}{16}
\end{align*}

We want find $a$'s such that the above expressions will be positive integers. From $297-31a>0$ we get $a<\frac{297}{31}$. For integer $a$'s this means that $a\le9$. (So we do not really have that many possibilities to try, only $a=1,2,\dots,9$.)

If we want $7a\equiv 73 \pmod 4$, this is equivalent to $a\equiv1\pmod4$.
Moreover, we want $31a\equiv297\pmod{16}$, which gives us $a\equiv7\pmod{16}$.
So $b$ and $c$ are integers only if $a=16k+7$.